# IndexOf always returns 0

Tags: c#, indexof

I have the following code made to check indices in the line underneath and return it as an int array, but the indices always return 0 for some reason. I do not see the problem that is going on here.

```
public static int[] FindIndex(char x, string parsedString)
{
    int[] Indices = new int[11];
    int lastPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
    {
        lastPos = parsedString.IndexOf(x, lastPos+1);
        Indices[i] = lastPos;
    }
    // Following WriteLines are for debugging            
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[4]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[5]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[6]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[7]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[8]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[9]);
    Console.WriteLine(Indices[10]);
    return Indices;
}
```

The string I'm finding the indices for is:

Card ID,Card Name,Card Set,Card Type,Class,Rarity,Mana Cost,Attack,Health,Card Mechanics,Race,Collectible

The index char x is ',', and the parsedString is the string.

Comment: Your for loop never runs because `i > 10` is false for `i = 0`. It should be `i <= 10`?

Comment: You could create a small runnable example for things like this.

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger, which *should always be your first course of action*, would have immediately revealed that you are never populating your array.

Answer (score 1):

You loop Condition(`i > 10`) is always false, because of which the loop never executes, as initial value of i is set to 0

This needs to be changed to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

Having said so, there is another problem. If your string contains more than 10 delimiter character, you are limiting yourself to 10 detectable indices here.

Instead of approach based on a fixed size array, you could use the following

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndex(char x, string parsedString)
    {
        int lastPos = 0;
        while(lastPos<parsedString.Length)
        {
            lastPos = parsedString.IndexOf(x, lastPos+1);
            if(lastPos==-1) break;
            Console.WriteLine(lastPos);
            yield return lastPos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be `i < 11` or `i <= 10` as indicated by the array size

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] Indices = new int[11];
```

C# will zero initialize the elements of an integer array.

```
 for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
```

Here `i` starts at 0, but the condition is `i > 10` so the loop never runs. As a result the array still contains just the original zero values.